# CORS Error in Pentaho 7.1 CE

Tags: cors, pentaho, tomcat8

I am trying to integrate Pentaho 7.1 CE version with an Angular application and there I have to access the Pentaho context. For authentication purposes here, I am using a cookies-based API and passing the parameter. During this, I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8083/pentaho/j_spring_security_check. Redirect from
>   'http://localhost:8083/pentaho/j_spring_security_check' to
>   'http://localhost:8083/pentaho/Home;jsessionid=E0B8FFAFE57EDEC09DB8229457FAA7B4'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

I have already enable CORS in Pentaho and modified the `web.xml` file located at
`pentaho-server\tomcat\conf`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Can anyone suggest to me what I am missing here? Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue when I tried to create a webapi and consume it from an Angular2 web app. I fixed it by installing the nuget from [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)
in the webapi solution. There’s a [how-to-use explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) of the nuget
which worked just fine for me.

Comment: @ Alaa ZainThanks for your quick response.then u means i have to install nuget package in the angular 4 ?please guide me

Comment: you need to install first Nuget4Code and use it to install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors in your project

Comment: In Pentaho, though modified necessary settings, its not working. webapi.cors is useful, if you are using asp.net webapi only. Here is the concern between angular 2 and pentaho/tomcat url